# Bootstrap col is adding extra height instead of wrapping img tightly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `img` nested in a `col`. However, the `col` is larger than the image. It's as if there is `padding` at the bottom, but I don't see any. Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKW21.jpg

There is another img nested within a separate col in the same row, but that img is the exact same size.

EDIT* I tried two fixes per a suggestion: display: block and vertical-align: bottom (separately), neither of which worked.

```
 .img-shrink {
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
  }
```

```
 <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-3 body-padding text-center">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-shrink" src="img/dog-beer.jpg" alt="beer">
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 body-padding text-center">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-shrink" src="img/dog-treats.jpg" alt="treats">   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-2 align-text-top">
                    <h4 class="product-header">Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 align-text-top">
                    <h4 class="product-header">Lorem Ipsum</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion, but it didn't work. I tried both methods they suggested with no success.

Comment: What is the class `body-padding`? Is it adding any padding?

Comment: Also are those images are of same dimensions? Beer and treats?

Comment: It adds padding-top to those images to space them out from the row above them. And yes, the images are exactly the same - 325x325 px each

Answer (score 0):

After playing around, I figured it out. The col is sized to the actual size of my image, not the max-width/height: 80% image that the browser renders. If anyone knows a way around this without resizing the original image, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once and see if it works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>CSS Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-3">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img.jpg" alt="beer">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="image.jpg" alt="treats">   
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-3 align-text-top text-center">
            <h4 class="product-header">Lorem Ipsum</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 align-text-top text-center">
            <h4 class="product-header">Lorem Ipsum</h4>
        </div>
    </div>       
</body>
</html>
```